# Playing a mp3 using MediaElement in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm trying to play an mp3 using MediaElement in Windows Phone 7. Here's the code. Please help me, I don't even get an error for this... But the song also doesn't play...

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.Source = new Uri("Song.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
        if (mediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            button1.Content = "Pause";
            mediaElement.Pause();
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Content = "Play";
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
    }
```

XAML Page

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <MediaElement Height="201" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,6,0,0" Name="mediaElement" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,213,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438" />
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, that the URI of the file is corrent. And the Song.mp3 needs to set as "Content" instead of as "Resource" file. And I think you also need to set "Copy to target if newer" on file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer tbe... But that didn't work. Is there any other reason you can think of? I edited the code above. For that also don't get 'paused' on button, when playing is stopped. That means the song is not playing... :-(

Comment: Does the URL work? Please try it by using the URI with the "mediaplayer task"

Comment: Hi , I think it's a problem in my emulator. Does anyone know, how to reset the settings in vs2010 for windows phone? I tried the same code in my other machine, and it works fine...

Comment: emulator settings automatically get rest when you close it and open again. did you trying restart your machine? also check whether sound is muted for emulator.

Comment: OMG, I'm so sorry..... It's my bad... I've turned off the sound for WP7 Emulator..... :O

Comment: That's funny. Atleast mark the question as solved and distribute points

Answer (score 0):

The media element need to load its media before you can call Play(), otherwise nothing will happen. The event MediaOpened is fired when the media is loaded.

```
myMediaElement.MediaOpened += (o, args) => myMediaElement.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

In XAML :

```
{<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,160,12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Button Content="Xaml Play" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" />
            <MediaElement x:Name="playSound" Source="sounds/Loose.wav" AutoPlay="False" Height="0" Width="0"  /></Grid>}
```

"

In C# :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            playSound.Play();
        }
```

Hope This Helps :)

Comment: <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,160,12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Button Content="Xaml Play" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" />
            <MediaElement x:Name="playSound" Source="sounds/Loose.wav" AutoPlay="False" Height="0" Width="0"  /></Grid>

Comment: dont use this, use the XNA SoundEffect

Comment: Yes, That is a better way to do it